# how the pointer In MySql Index(B+ tree) keep valid while the Index may store in disk and come back in another page?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have known that the B+ tree index in MySql Innode engine is stored in pages(The pages are managed by MySql). One node is on one page. And i have known that MySql will put some nodes to disk when the free pages are not enough, and then sometimes read the nodes back from disk , put them on some free pages again. So here is my question :

1, IF one node has a pointer to one of its child node while the child node is on page 1 now. The pointer to the child node is 0x7c11111111111111 (bacause the address of the child node is 0x7c11111111111111), for example.

2, Then the free pages are not enough ,so MySql put the child node on disk , and sometimes read the child node back form disk to one page again , for example page 2(because page 2 is free now).

3, In my opinion , The address of the child node has changed (not 0x7c11111111111111 again , because the node is on page 2 , not page 1 again).  So how the father node still can find the child node while the pointer is still 0x7c11111111111111 ?

Answer (score 1):

Each node in an InnoDB B+Tree (either data or index) is permanently numbered by "block number", which is essentially its location in the file (`.ibd` or `ibdata1`).  When a node is fetched into the buffer_pool, it is put wherever there is a place for it.  A lookup mechanism maps the block number to the RAM address in the buffer_pool.

If that block is modified, it will eventually be written back to disk at the same spot in the file.

If that block is split (due, for example, to `INSERTing` too many rows into it), then another block is pulled from a free list for the split.  Because of the `+` in "B+Tree", this means that a couple of links need to be updated to slip this new block into the sequential chain of B+Tree blocks.  All of this is done while the blocks are in the buffer_pool.  And the parent to these two nodes needs updating, and possibly also being split.

A block that is modified for any reason, is marked as "dirty".  A background task takes care of eventually writing dirty blocks to disk.

The blocks are never (except coincidentally) numbered consecutively 1,2,3, etc.  The "next" block could have any "number".  Furthermore, the numbers are not necessarily monotonic, since a 'free' block to satisfy a 'split' might have a smaller number.

All of the above is more complex due to 'tablespaces', buffer_pool_instances, extensions to ibdata1, undo, redo, history chain, and other things.